# Android: Passing Checked items from a ListView to another activity with a ListView

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to pass checked items from one listview to another listview in a separate activity. Ideally, the user would click all of the items they wanted, then click a button; then, the button would take all of the items from the rows clicked to the new activity. The problem that I keep having is when I click on the row; all of the information shows up on the next activity instead of the individual rows there were selected.

```
       @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                adapterTwo.setCheckBox(position);
                adapterTwo.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        practiceFinal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String entry = "";
                String judge ="";
                Integer points = 0;
                Integer work = 0;
                Integer design = 0;
                Integer doc = 0;
                Integer pres= 0;
                Integer safety= 0;
                Integer diff = 0;
                String ribbon ="";
                Intent intent = new Intent(CSS.this, FinalCSS.class);
                for (Team hold: adapterTwo.getTeamArrayList())
                {
                    if (hold.isChecked())
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        entry += " "+ hold.getEntryNumber();
                        judge += hold.getTeamJudgeNumber();
                        points+= hold.getTotalPoints();
                        work+= hold.getWorkmanship();
                        design += hold.getDesign();
                        doc += hold.getDocumnetation();
                        pres+= hold.getPresentation();
                        safety += hold.getSafety();
                        diff += hold.getDifficulty();
                        ribbon += hold.getRibbon();

                        intent.putExtra( "KeyEntry", entry);
                        intent.putExtra("KeyJudge", judge);
                        intent.putExtra("KeyPoints", points);
                        intent.putExtra("KeyWork", work);
                        intent.putExtra("KeyDesign", design);
                        intent.putExtra("KeyDoc",doc);
                        intent.putExtra("KeyPres", pres);
                        intent.putExtra("KeySafety", safety);
                        intent.putExtra("KeyRibbon", ribbon);
                        intent.putExtra("KeyDiff", diff);
                    }
                }
                   startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

```
 listView = findViewById(R.id.listViewFinal);
        teamsList= new ArrayList<>();

            String entry = getIntent().getStringExtra("KeyEntry");
            String judge=getIntent().getStringExtra("KeyJudge");
            Integer points= getIntent().getIntExtra("KeyPoints",0);
            Integer workmanship=getIntent().getIntExtra("KeyWork",0);
            Integer design=getIntent().getIntExtra("KeyDesign",0);
            Integer documentation =getIntent().getIntExtra("KeyDoc",0);
            Integer pres = getIntent().getIntExtra("KeyPres",0);
            Integer difficulty =getIntent().getIntExtra("KeyDiff",0);
            Integer safety =getIntent().getIntExtra("KeySafety",0);
            String ribbon= getIntent().getStringExtra("KeyRibbon");
            Team teams = null;
            teams = new Team(judge,entry,points, workmanship,design,documentation,pres,difficulty,safety,ribbon,true);
            teamsList.add(teams);
            Team teamsT = null;
            teamsT = new Team(judge,entry,points, workmanship,design,documentation,pres,difficulty,safety,ribbon,true);
            teamsList.add(teamsT);

            TeamAdapterTwo adapterTwo = new TeamAdapterTwo(FinalCSS.this, teamsList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapterTwo);
```

[Second Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHa6f.png)[First Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKUVZ.png)[Second Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WLae.png)

Comment: Please post your code using code tags, not images of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concatenate the information on a global variable. Thus, if we trace the `points` attribute evolution, we have:

- points = 0
- points += 1 (points = 1)
- points += 2 (points = 3)
- points += 3 (points = 6)
- points += 4 (points = 10)

Moreover, `intent.putExtra` erase the old value associated to a key, so at each iteration of the loop, you are replacing the old value of points by the new one. Therefore, at the end, you will give `points = 10` to the second Activity.

You have two options:

- Create a unique key for each `hold` but it will not be easy for the second Activity to know this unique key.
- Instead of put an integer as extra, put an array of integers (I recommend this way)

However, you seem to have an other issue because the final value of `points` is the sum of all lines rather than the sum of the checked ones.